# Form Upload with image file using bootstrapValidator not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrapvalidator

I'm trying to make a player registration form on our site for a sports tournament. I'm using bootstrap and jquery to validate the form but I can't seem to get the image uploading to server and move the file to the directory. It uploads the form data but not the image. Driving me nuts, done plenty of searches but no avail.

here is my jquery code and my html page.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
      $('#success_message').slideDown({
        opacity: "show"
      }, "slow") // Do something ...
      $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

      var bv = form.data('bootstrapValidator');
      // Use Ajax to submit form data
      $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }, 'json');
    },
    fields: {
      first_name: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 2,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your first name'
          }
        }
      },
      last_name: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 2,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your last name'
          }
        }
      },
      email: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your email address'
          },
          emailAddress: {
            message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
          }
        }
      },
      phone: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your phone number'
          },
          phone: {
            country: 'US',
            message: 'Please supply a vaild phone number with area code'
          }
        }
      },
      address: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 8,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your street address'
          }
        }
      },
      city: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 4,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your city'
          }
        }
      },
      state: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please select your state'
          }
        }
      },
      zip: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your zip code'
          },
          zipCode: {
            country: 'US',
            message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
          }
        }
      },
      comment: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 10,
            max: 200,
            message: 'Please enter at least 10 characters and no more than 200'
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply a description of your project'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah')
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
        .height(200);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'>
</script>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
  <form class="well form-horizontal" action="UploadForm.php" method="post" id="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input name="firstname" placeholder="firstname" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- more input vari -->

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
          <input type="file" id="imgfile" name="player_image" onchange="readURL(this);" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
          <img src="images/DefaultImage.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
          <figcaption>Example</figcaption>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
          <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image will appear here" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success
        <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></em> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset 
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                      Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send">
                    </span>
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>



    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: add your `readUrl()` function, your created snippet had already errors in it I just fixed it, add your relevant code to make the example run the same way as you are experiencing it.

Comment: I have added the readUrl() funcation, And to claify when submitting the form I am unable to get the post data for the file/image. I am getting that information by using $_FILES["player_image"]["name"] then using move_uploaded_file to the save to directory on server/locally.

Comment: And how do you hope your File will get converted to a JSON format? Don' want to use Mjölnir yet, but *Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax*

Comment: I used https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MadxaE?editors=001 as a template to do my form. but can't figure out files. hopefully this helps clarify things. Kaiido I have no idea what a JSON file is. I read the attached link you sent but it seems to be different problem then mine.

Comment: You are using `$.post` with the format option set to `"JSON"`. [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a syntax allowing us to represent basic JS data formats as strings, but it can't represent binary data such as an image file. The link I gave you show you the correct way to send binary files using jQuery.

Comment: Ok thanks, If i replace the submitHandler portion with the code that you supplied. Well that submit form data along with the image file. I ill try it out. hopefully that works.